# Определение стилей для элементов виджета

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо изолировать стили для виджета, который будет встраиваться на сторонние сайты. Например, на сайте определены несколько стилей для кнопки, которые влияют на кнопку во вставляемом виджете. All:unset * не подходит, т.к. поддерживается не во всех браузерах. Т.к. различных элементов в виджете множество, и у каждого из них может быть множество различных свойств, как лучше всего определить для каждого элемента все его возможные свойства, чтобы они не наследовались из стилей сайта?